# is there a way to use user AD token to run pipeline in azure instead of using service connection, PAT and job token

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-pipelines

I am new to Azure DevOps, I want to understand if there is a way to use user token to run pipeline instead of agents token that will be created while running the pipeline.

Comment: Please describe what you want to accomplish by doing this. What is the goal?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you want to run pipeline with your personal identity which result in having your own pwersonal token instead of System.AccessToken. This is no possible. Pipeline runner has own (limited identity). However, if you want to you can get information how ran the pipeline by checking these variables:

- Build.RequestedFor
- Build.RequestedForEmail
- Build.RequestedForId

Please check this [section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#how-are-the-identity-variables-set) to understand what values can you find in these variables.